# change value of text using getElementsByName

Tags: javascript, html, forms, getelementsbytagname

I have `firstName` text that I want to change his value but it not work -

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" />
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">
      document.getElementsByName("firstName").[0].value = "New Value " ;
</script>
```

How can I change this value  ?

Comment: Remove the period after the `getElementsByName("firstName")`, before the `[0]`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[That's not syntactically valid JS.](http://www.jshint.com/reports/657103) Remove the extra `.`:

```
//                                    ↓↓
document.getElementsByName("firstName")[0].value = "New Value " ;
//                                    ↑↑
```

and [the rest will work](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/uYxdY/).

Comment: @AdamRackis ['tis not ASCII at all](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2191/index.htm) `;-)`